# Bootsfaces scrollUp and Gliphicon

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, bootsfaces

I'm working with a JSF project that uses BootsFaces 1.1.3

I've tried with the following without luck

```
<b:scrollUp text="" distance="150" class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-up"/>
```

How can I set a glyphicon icon using the b:scrollUp?

Answer (score 0):

I didn't try it yet, but according to the documentation of the plugin you have to set the attribute `image="true"`. The image itself must be defined in a CSS snippet:

```
#scrollUp {
    background-image: url("../../img/top.png");
    bottom: 20px;
    right: 20px;
    width: 38px;    /* Width of image */
    height: 38px;   /* Height of image */
}
```

To use a Glyphicon, it's probably the best approach to look up the Glyphicon definition and to copy it into the CSS snippet:

```
    .glyphicon {
      position: relative;
      top: 1px;
      display: inline-block;
      font-family: 'Glyphicons Halflings';
      font-style: normal;
      font-weight: normal;
      line-height: 1;
      -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
      -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
    }
    .glyphicon-chevron-up 
    { 
       &:before { content: "\e113"; } 
    }
```